# Trying to improve JS technique with Revealing Module Pattern - simple example

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

Like others lately, I'm trying to transition from a more (basic) declarative JS style to a more modular style based on my reading of [Addy Osmani's Essential JS Design Patterns book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

While I roughly grasp the Module Pattern idea, I'm not quite sure I'm applying the techniques properly. Obviously, I understand there are "many ways to skin a cat" and [everyone has opinions which may or may not always be correct](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/#comment-259905). I'm just looking to start somewhere that makes sense to me.

For example, given the following HTML and JS, the code below works (assuming jQuery loaded). However, it still feels to me something is not quite right with the implementation.

**HTML**

```
<div id="someDiv">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Using Revealing Module Pattern:
// - add attribute to div
// - add click event to h2 which toggles p
var myMod = (function () {

    // defined & cached within the local scope
    var d = $('#someDiv'),
      h = $('h2'),
      addAttribute = function () {
        d.attr("data-info", "something here");
        addClickEvent();
      },
      addClickEvent = function () {
        h.click(function () {
            toggleP(this);
        });
      },
      toggleP = function (el) {
        $(el).siblings().toggle();
      };


    // Return public object 
    return {
      init: addAttribute
    };

})();

myMod.init();
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/skube/fED33/)

Comment: There are a few smells (unnecessary many functions, `$()` executed before domready, possible unnecessarily exposed `init` method) but nothing particularly wrong with the module pattern. What exactly does feel not quite right?

Comment: well, for one, i see no purpose in having variables named `d` and `h`,  if you want to make the code smaller, minify it before you deploy. that of course has nothing to do with your usage of the revealing module pattern.

Comment: This is a simplified example. In a real world case I would probably use `d` and `h` multiple times thus making more sense for assigning them in the first place. Would simply placing `myMod.init()` inside `$(document).ready(...)` would fix the domready?

Comment: Yes, that would be enough to force it to execute on dom ready. My comment was more pointed at the name of the variable used, not the fact that the variable was created.

Comment: @skube: Nope, as the `d` and `h` are assigned outside (before) of `init`. You'd have to move the jQuery selections inside `init` as well.

Comment: @Bergi: Ok, but how? Move them inside the addAttribute expression?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or even pass them as arguments to there.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean having to pass them as arguments to every function in which they are used? Seems a bit repetitive.